# STM32F0 UART + DMA + Interrupt with STM32CubeMX HAL 1.2.1 problem

Tags: c, uart, stm32f0, dma, stm32cubemx

Hello fellow electronics engineers!

I'm having a bit of a problem with setting up the STM32F072-Nucleo board as a small shell (I want to send commands via UART and set/get various settings of the application I'm making.) using the UART with DMA in interrupt mode.

The code is based on [BrinirController](https://github.com/hammerfet/BrinirController/blob/master/Firmware/serial.c). The problem is that while I can receive the first character and echo it back, after that first interrupt the MCU does not do another interrupt if I try to write another character. The HAL I'm using is 1.2.1 (together with the STM32CubeMX) and it does not have the macro `__HAL_UART_FLUSH_DRREGISTER(&huart2)` for flushing the UART's RX data buffer.

Does the function `__HAL_UART_SEND_REQ(&huart2, UART_RXDATA_FLUSH_REQUEST)` do the same thing as the macro `__HAL_UART_FLUSH_DRREGISTER(&huart2)` in the previous version of HAL?

Could this be the problem: the RX data buffer is full so it just won't start another interrupt while it's not cleared/read from?

The `RxCpltCallback` callback function is called only the first time I enter something in the serial terminal... It just won't interrupt the second time... I've tried everything, it seems! :D What could be the solution? I'm using the STM32F072RBT6 (STM32F072-Nucleo board)

The code goes like this:

```
UART_HandleTypeDef huart2;
DMA_HandleTypeDef hdma_usart2_rx;
DMA_HandleTypeDef hdma_usart2_tx;

/* USART2 init function */

void MX_USART2_UART_Init(void)
{

  huart2.Instance = USART2;
  huart2.Init.BaudRate = 9600;
  huart2.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
  huart2.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
  huart2.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
  huart2.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
  huart2.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
  huart2.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;
  huart2.Init.OneBitSampling = UART_ONEBIT_SAMPLING_DISABLED ;
  huart2.AdvancedInit.AdvFeatureInit = UART_ADVFEATURE_NO_INIT;
  HAL_UART_Init(&huart2);

}

void HAL_UART_MspInit(UART_HandleTypeDef* huart)
{

  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct;
  if(huart->Instance==USART2)
  {
  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART2_MspInit 0 */

  /* USER CODE END USART2_MspInit 0 */
    /* Peripheral clock enable */
    __USART2_CLK_ENABLE();

    /**USART2 GPIO Configuration    
    PA2     ------> USART2_TX
    PA3     ------> USART2_RX 
    */
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_2;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_PULLUP;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_LOW;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF1_USART2;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_3;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_LOW;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF1_USART2;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

    /* Peripheral DMA init*/

    hdma_usart2_rx.Instance = DMA1_Channel5;
    hdma_usart2_rx.Init.Direction = DMA_PERIPH_TO_MEMORY;
    hdma_usart2_rx.Init.PeriphInc = DMA_PINC_DISABLE;
    hdma_usart2_rx.Init.MemInc = DMA_MINC_ENABLE;
    hdma_usart2_rx.Init.PeriphDataAlignment = DMA_PDATAALIGN_BYTE;
    hdma_usart2_rx.Init.MemDataAlignment = DMA_MDATAALIGN_BYTE;
    hdma_usart2_rx.Init.Mode = DMA_NORMAL;
    hdma_usart2_rx.Init.Priority = DMA_PRIORITY_MEDIUM;
    HAL_DMA_Init(&hdma_usart2_rx);

    __HAL_LINKDMA(huart,hdmarx,hdma_usart2_rx);

    hdma_usart2_tx.Instance = DMA1_Channel4;
    hdma_usart2_tx.Init.Direction = DMA_MEMORY_TO_PERIPH;
    hdma_usart2_tx.Init.PeriphInc = DMA_PINC_DISABLE;
    hdma_usart2_tx.Init.MemInc = DMA_MINC_ENABLE;
    hdma_usart2_tx.Init.PeriphDataAlignment = DMA_PDATAALIGN_BYTE;
    hdma_usart2_tx.Init.MemDataAlignment = DMA_MDATAALIGN_BYTE;
    hdma_usart2_tx.Init.Mode = DMA_NORMAL;
    hdma_usart2_tx.Init.Priority = DMA_PRIORITY_LOW;
    HAL_DMA_Init(&hdma_usart2_tx);

    __HAL_LINKDMA(huart,hdmatx,hdma_usart2_tx);

  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART2_MspInit 1 */

  /* USER CODE END USART2_MspInit 1 */
  }
}
```

and the interrupt callback function:

```
void HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart)
{
  __HAL_UART_SEND_REQ(&huart2, UART_RXDATA_FLUSH_REQUEST); // Clear the buffer to prevent overrun
  int i = 0;
  HAL_UART_Transmit_DMA(&huart2, (uint8_t *)&rxBuffer, 1);

  if (rxBuffer == 8 || rxBuffer == 127) // If Backspace or del
    {
      printf(" \b"); // "\b space \b" clears the terminal character. Remember we just echoced a \b so don't need another one here, just space and \b
      rxindex--;
      if (rxindex < 0) rxindex = 0;
    }

  else if (rxBuffer == '\n' || rxBuffer == '\r') // If Enter
    {
      executeSerialCommand(rxString);
      rxString[rxindex] = 0;
      rxindex = 0;
      for (i = 0; i < MAXSTRING; i++) rxString[i] = 0; // Clear the string buffer
    }

  else
    {
      rxString[rxindex] = rxBuffer; // Add that character to the string
      rxindex++;
      if (rxindex > MAXSTRING) // User typing too much, we can't have commands that big
    {
      rxindex = 0;
      for (i = 0; i < MAXSTRING; i++) rxString[i] = 0; // Clear the string buffer
      printf("\r\nKonsole> ");
    }
    }
}
```

Of course, I'm calling the HAL_UART_Receive_DMA(&huart2, &rxBuffer, 1) in the main routine before the infinite loop and have defined these variables as buffers:

```
uint8_t rxBuffer = '\000';
uint8_t rxString[MAXSTRING];
int rxindex = 0;
```

Answer (score 5):

Switch the RX DMA mode to DMA_CIRCULAR.
Normal DMA mode executes once and you have to configure it again. Circular mode allows you to do the same operation until you explicitly stop it.

Comment: I had similar case, and switching the **USART RX DMA Mode** (within Cube's DMA configuration window) from to NORMAL to **CIRCULAR** has helped -> now ISRs for characters/data being received are being called regularly and do not require re-enabling them (which just means they work more stable). Thank you for the hint ! :-)